Can anyone know how to execute using only .gguf file , without any test-LLM-23B-m.safetensors.index.json ,test-LLM-23B-m.safetensors
from auto_gptq import AutoGPTQForCausalLM,BaseQuantizeConfig
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
def run_model():
    try:
        #Check if CUDA is available and set device accordingly
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            device = torch.device("cuda")
            print("Using CUDA")
        else:
            device = torch.device("cpu")
            print("CUDA not available, Using CPU ")

        quantize_config = BaseQuantizeConfig(
        bits=4,
        group_size=64,
        desc_act=False 
    )             
        
        model_path = "D:\\modelpath\\"           
        model_basename = "test-LLM-23B-m"          
        
        #Create the quantized model
        model = AutoGPTQForCausalLM.from_quantized(
            model_path=model_path,
            model_basename=model_basename,
            model_name_or_path=model_path,
            use_safetensors=True,
            # trust_remote_code=True,
            # device_map="auto",
            # use_triton=False, 
            quantize_config=quantize_config  # You can provide quantization configuration if needed
        )
        
        model.to(device)        
        tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path, use_fast=True)        
        model.eval()
        prompt = "what is java language"        
        input_ids = tokenizer.encode(prompt,
                                    add_special_tokens=False,
                                    return_tensors="pt")       
        tokens = model.generate(
            input_ids.to(device=model.device),
            max_new_tokens=128,
            do_sample=True,
            temperature=0.1,
            top_p=1.0,
            repetition_penalty=1.0,
            top_k=0
        )
       
        out = tokenizer.decode(tokens[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
        print(" Output Text    ", out)       

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error:", str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
     
    run_model()

test-LLM-23B-m  -- this is .gguf file . while executing the code in my laptop using CPU it shows below error
Can anyone know how to execute using  only  .gguf file , without any test-LLM-23B-m.safetensors.index.json ,test-LLM-23B-m.safetensors
WARNING - Exllamav2 kernel is not installed, reset disable_exllamav2 to True. This may because you installed auto_gptq using a pre-build wheel on Windows,
in which exllama_kernels are not compiled. To use exllama_kernels to further speedup inference, you can re-install auto_gptq from source.
WARNING - CUDA kernels for auto_gptq are not installed, this will result in very slow inference speed. This may because:

You disabled CUDA extensions compilation by setting BUILD_CUDA_EXT=0 when install auto_gptq from source.
You are using pytorch without CUDA support.
CUDA and nvcc are not installed in your device.
Error: Could not find a model in D:\modelpath\ with a name in test-LLM-23B-m.safetensors.index.json, test-LLM-23B-m.safetensors.
Please specify the argument model_basename to use a custom file name.

